# Define the action of an operator.

Tags: combinatorics

Let $f(z)$  be a polynomial in one variable $z$. I know that after factorization it can be written in the form 
$$
f(z)=(1-z^{n_1})^{m_1}(1-z^{n_2})^{m_2}\cdots(1-z^{n_k})^{m_k}, m_i,n_i,k \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Let $A$  be an operator that sends $f(z)$ to 
$$
Af(z):=(1+z^{n_1})^{m_1}(1+z^{n_2})^{m_2}\cdots(1+z^{n_k})^{m_k}.
$$

**Question.** Define the action $A$ of $f(z)$ in the not-factorized  form.

If $n_i$ are odd  then  seems  $Af(z)=f(-z).$ But what be if some of $n_i$  are even?

Comment: Is it demanded that A be linear? If not, try $f(z^2)/f(z)$.

Comment: I agree with LutzL

Comment: Oh yes!!!..very simple solution..Thank you!